# How do I can load rails engine webpacker compiled js file inside rails application on webpacker:compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-engines, webpacker

I'm using a rails engine with webpacker and compiling it inside my rails application but I need to copy paste copiled engine manifest.json file inside webpacker:compile manifest.json. I want to load a single manifest.json on the compilation my rails application without additinally compile engine and copy past manifest.json content.